# Duplicate uniqueKey Solr Parent document

Tags: solr, parent-child, dih

I have Solr 6.6 parent child document with id  as `uniqueKey`.

I have a parent document with the same ID, but no overwrite occurs in update.

How can I prevent this?

```
<dataConfig>
    <document>
        <entity name="Parent" pk="ParentID" processor="SqlEntityProcessor"  rootEntity="true"
                query=" select ParentID,ParentName From Parent Order by ParentID">

            <entity name="Child1" child="true"  processor="SqlEntityProcessor" 
                    query="select ParentID,ChildID,ChildName From Child order by ParentID"
                    join="zipper"
                    cacheKey="PartID" cacheLookup="Parts.PartID" 
                    cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache">
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Query response

```
{
    ParentID:1
    ParentName:P1
    {
        ParentID:1
        ParentName:P1
        {
            ParentID:1
            ChildID:1
            ChildName:c1
        }
```

Comment: Your child and parent document has the same id? or you have two parent documents with the same id? Do you want a child document to overwrite the parent, or do you want both to exist? Or do you have a parent document and you're indexing another parent with the same id and no overwriting is happening? Please be a lot more specific in your question, it's hard to say what you're asking right now.

Comment: My Parent and Child has one to many relationship the duplication  in my Parent . ID want  to overwrite parent  and it's related child with new one.

Comment: now i find duplication in parent document only no duplication in child .

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what you're asking. Could you add examples to your question and how to reproduce?

Comment: Please update your question with any further details and add proper formatting, don't use the comment section. Also show what you've tried and what have failed.

Comment: I'm  Add sample from my schema.xml  and response query, thank you for you replying